# About the positive and negative parts of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f, f_1, f_2, \dots :\Omega \to \bar{\mathbb R}$ be functions such that $f_n \uparrow f$. Is it true that the positive and negative parts of $f_n$ also converge to the positive and negative parts of $f$, respectively? In other words, $f_n^{+} \uparrow f^+$ and $f_n^- \downarrow f^- ?$

I'm trying to prove this by definition, but I'm stuck at this inequality: Given $\omega \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon > 0 :$ $|(f_n^+(\omega) - f^+(\omega)) - (f_n^-(\omega) - f^-(\omega))| < \epsilon$ for some $n \geq N$.

Comment: Since $g^+(x)=\max\{0,g(x)\}$, this follows immediately from the continuity of the function $\max\{0,u\}$ (and similarly for the negative parts), even without the hypothesis that the $f_n$ are increasing.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks, it is straightforward that way.